# Store data from a specific content type in a different database?

Tags: nodes, database

Was not able to find a previously asked question. But is it possible and or worthwhile?

Background: setting up a new feature that will host a lot of data. Want to separate it from the rest of the site so if something happens to that data the rest of the site, users e.g will not be touched.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without a lot of custom code. Primarily because Drupal stores field content in separate database tables. There is not the one single table that holds the content of all nodes of a specific content type. And fields are also re-usable across different content types. You would need to create your own [storage engine](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/group/field_storage/7).

Wouldn't an intelligent backup strategy be enough to assure data security in your case?

Comment: We have a backup strategy in place, I was just thinking from an architectural perspective. Thanks!